No Activity found to handle Intent for NFC
I am trying to detect the nearby NFC enabled device by activating NFC on the device.
I am getting No Activity found to handle Intent error.
[Error: Could not open URL 'intent:#Intent;action=android.settings.NFC_SETTINGS;end': No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=intent: flg=0x10000000 }]
Below is the code:
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { View, Button, Alert, Platform, Linking } from 'react-native';
import NfcManager from 'react-native-nfc-manager';
// import NfcManager, { NfcEvents } from 'react-native-nfc-manager';

const LoginScreen = () => {
  const [nfcActivated, setNfcActivated] = useState(false);

  const handleNFCPress = async () => {
    try {
      if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
        // Check if NFC is already activated
        if (!nfcActivated) {
          await askNFCPermission();
        } else {
          Alert.alert('NFC Already Activated', 'NFC is already activated on this device');
        }
      } else {
        Alert.alert('NFC Not Supported', 'NFC is not supported on this device');
      }
    } catch (ex) {
      Alert.alert('Error', 'Failed to activate NFC');
    }
  };

  const askNFCPermission = async () => {
    try {
      Alert.alert(
        'Enable NFC',
        'Please enable NFC in your device settings to use this feature.',
        [
          { text: 'Cancel', style: 'cancel' },
          { text: 'Go to Settings', onPress: () => openNfcSettings() },
        ]
      );
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Failed to ask NFC permission:', error);
    }
  };

  const openNfcSettings = () => {
    // Open NFC settings using an intent URI
    Linking.openURL('intent:#Intent;action=android.settings.NFC_SETTINGS;end').catch(err => console.error('An error occurred', err));
  };

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <Button title="NFC" onPress={handleNFCPress} />
    </View>
  );
};

export default LoginScreen;

